# Can someone compare a Fuzzy Query to a LuceneDictionary solution?

Tags: autocomplete, lucene, spell-checking

According to this post on [how to do query auto-completionsuggestions in lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120180/how-to-do-query-auto-completionsuggestions-in-lucene) getting "Did You Mean" functionality best involves using a LuceneDictionary. But I probably would have used a fuzzy query for this before reading this post. Now I'm wondering which is faster, which is easier to implement?

Comment: You may find helpful this discussion:  http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Comment: While not about Lucene, nor an answer, that page is a good read, and makes Python look awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at some NGram wrappers for Lucene. They are the best ways to do the "did you mean" functionality in Lucene. I [found this page](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/package-summary.html) for the docs.