# Howto perform a 'contains' search rather than 'starts with' using Lucene.Net

Tags: c#, search, lucene, lucene.net

We use Lucene.NET to implement a full text search on a clients website. The search itself works already but we now want to implement a modification.

Currently all terms get appended a `*` which leads Lucene to perform what I would classify as a `StartsWith` search.

In the future we would like to have a search that performs something like a `Contains` rather than a `StartsWith`.

We use

- Lucene.Net 2.9.2.2
- StandardAnalyzer
- default QueryParser

Samples:

`(Title:Orch*)` matches: `Orchestra`

but:

`(Title:rch*)` does not match: `Orchestra`

We want the first and the second one to both match `Orchestra`.

Basically I want the exact opposite of what was asked in this question, I'm not sure why for this person Lucene performed a `Contains` and rather than a `StartsWith` by default:
[Why is this Lucene query a "contains" instead of a "startsWith"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605899/why-is-this-lucene-query-a-contains-instead-of-a-startswith)

How can we make this happen?
I have the feeling it has something to do with the Analyzer but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First off, I assume you're using StandardAnalyzer, or something similar. Your linked question fail to understand that you search for terms, and his case `a*` will match "Fleet Africa" because it's tokenized into "fleet" and "africa".

You need to call `QueryParser.SetAllowLeadingWildcard(true)` to be able to write queries like `field:*value*`. Are you actually changing the string that's passed to QueryParser?

You could parse the query as usual, and then implement a [QueryVisitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) that rewrites all `TermQuery` into `WildcardQuery`. That way you still support phrase searches.

I see no good things in rewriting queries into prefix- or wildcard-queries. There is very little shared between an orc, or a chest, and an Orchestra, but both words will match. Instead, hook up your customer with an analyzer that supports stemming, synonyms, and provide a spell correction feature to fix simple searching mistakes.

Comment: As search engine specs are often "do it like google", you can say that google don't seem to allow this. Try searching for "chestra" ;)

Comment: Thx, that was exactly what I was looking for, regarding the task itself: Well as so often, the client wants exactly this and is resistant against arguments ;) Also it's actually a non natural search for band names and event descriptions so things like stemming/synonyms etc. will most likely not be ideal in this case. Anyway works great now thx!

Comment: Watchout of the serious performance penalty of using `SetAllowLeadingWildcard(true)` - there's only a clue about that in the above answer. Also, depending on your intended usage, you might want to look into n-grams - ShingleFilter like Xodarap suggested in another answer.

Comment: Yes, allowing leading wildcards is a possible huge performance penalty. Queries like f:cat* are rewritten into something like f:(cat cats category ...) by using a TermsEnum. Leading wildcards means that it will need to iterate _all_ terms, instead of a small range. Similar issue exists with SQL Server indexes, they cant be used with LIKE '%value%'.

Answer (score 2):

@Simon Svensson probably gave the better answer (i.e. you don't need this), but if you do, you should use a [Shingle Filter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_2/api/contrib-analyzers/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html).

Note that this will make your index massively larger, since instead of just storing "orchestra", you will store "orc", "rch", "che", "hes"... But just having a plain term query with leading wildcards will be massively slow. It will essentially have to look through every single term in your corpus.

Comment: Can you explain how to configure/use shingle filter for this case?