# Matching entire sentence with spaces in lucene BooleanQuery

Tags: solr, lucene, lucene.net

I have a search string ,

```
Tulip INN Riyadhh
 Tulip INN Riyadhh LUXURY
 Suites of Tulip INN RIYAHdhh
```

I need search term , if i mention

```
 *Tulip INN Riyadhh*
```

it has to return all the three above, i have restriction that i have to achieve this without QueryParser or Analyser, it has to be only BooleanQuery/WildCardQuery/etc....

Regards,
Raghavan

Comment: So what is the issue you face with Wildcard & Boolean?

Comment: WildCard:                                                                                  
    WildcardQuery rp = new WildcardQuery (new Term("propertyName","Inn Riya")); -- It should match "Tulip Inn Riyadhh" but it's not matching , If i use Boolean or Regex it's matching with lines containing only Tulip and Riyadhh also. Actually i need query which applies regex to complete sentence ( means "*Inn Riyadhh*" should only look for sentence containing Inn Riyaddh completly.

Comment: How you index and generate your terms matters too in addition to searcher part. You need to edit your question about analyzers used for Indexing too and what string is indexed?Also mention , lucene version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here is a `PhraseQuery`. Let me explain.

I don't know which analyzer you're using, but I'll suppose you have a very basic one for simplicity, that just converts text to lowercase. Don't tell me you're not using an anlayzer since it's mandatory for Lucene to do any work, at least at the indexing stage - this is what defines the tokenizer and the token filter chain.

Here's how your strings would be tokenized in this example:

- `tulip` `inn` `ryiadhh`
- `tulip` `inn` `ryiadhh` `luxury`
- `suites` `of` `tulip` `inn` `ryiadhh`

Notice how these all contain the token sequence `tulip` `inn` `ryiadhh`. A sequence of tokens is what a `PhraseQuery` is looking for.

In Lucene.Net building such a query looks like this (untested):

```
var query = new PhraseQuery();
query.Add(new Term("propertyName", "tulip"));
query.Add(new Term("propertyName", "inn"));
query.Add(new Term("propertyName", "ryiadhh"));
```

Note that the terms need to match those produced by the analyzer (in this example, they're all lowercase). The `QueryParser` does this job for you by running parts of the query through the analyzer, but you'll have to do it yourself if you don't use the parser.

Now, why wouldn't `WildcardQuery` or `RegexQuery` work in this situation? These queries always match a *single* term, yet you need to match an *ordered sequence of terms*. For instance a `WildcardQuery` with the term `Riyadhh*` would find *all words starting with `Riyadhh`*.

A `BooleanQuery` with a collection of `TermQuery` `MUST` clauses would match any text that happens to contain these 3 terms in any order - not exactly what you want either.

Comment: If i use the PhraseQuery with SearchString "*Tulip Inn Riyad*"                   
 "Tulip Inn Riyad Executive"  matching,"Tulip Inn Riyadhhh!!" :Not Matching means it's recognizing only spaces, if any string got attach to search string it's not considering. If i use Regex or WildCard it matchid individual words also in Search String actually i need this behaviour, "Tulip Inn Riyad Executive"  Match, "Tulip Inn Riyadhhh!!"  Match,"Tulip Inn Coastal"  NoMatch ,"Tulipsss" No Match

Comment: @Raghavan that actually depends on the tokenizer. You need a tokenizer that throws away punctuation (ie tokenizes `Tulip Inn Riyadhhh!!` into `tulip` `inn` `ryiadhh`). What analyzer (or more precisely what tokenizer and token filters) are you using?

Comment: I tried with standard and keyword analyzer, But both is matching if exact phrase is present is some strings added to the phrase it's not matching, The reason i'm looking for this is i'm trying to replicate sql %like% functionality of sql in lucene, Where like %nn Riya% will match "Tulip Inn Riyadhh", where lucene is matching "Tulip I nn Riya dhh" not "Tulip Inn Riyadhh". Can you guide me how can use tokenizer to convert "Tulip I nn Riya dhh" to "Tulip Inn Riyadhh".

Comment: @Raghavan hmm... a `PhraseQuery` won't cut it. You'll need a `SpanNearQuery`, which contains `SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper` as the first and last span. Each of those would wrap a `WildcardQuery`. But you need to be aware that: 1. Lucene.Net does not have `SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper` AFAIK, maybe it's in the v4 prerelease (if not, you'd need to port it from the Java version yourself) and 2. a `WildcardQuery` of the form `*something` will be *incredibly* inefficient, as it will have to scan the *full* index. I suggest you edit your question in order to explain your requirement *much more precisely*.

Answer (score 1):

Lucas has the right idea, but there is a more specialized `MultiPhraseQuery` that can be used to build up a query based on the data that is already in the index to get a prefix match as [demonstrated in this unit test](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/1a980c4960becdbe74dc8bba31b2306da0087cef/src/Lucene.Net.Tests/Search/TestMultiPhraseQuery.cs#L55). The documentation of `MultiPhraseQuery` reads:

> `MultiPhraseQuery` is a generalized version of `PhraseQuery`, with an added method `Add(Term[])`. To use this class, to search for the phrase "Microsoft app*" first use `Add(Term)` on the term "Microsoft", then find all terms that have "app" as prefix using `IndexReader.GetTerms(Term)`, and use `MultiPhraseQuery.Add(Term[] terms)` to add them to the query.

As Lucas pointed out, a `*something` `WildCardQuery` is the way to do the suffix match, provided you understand the performance implications.

They can then be combined with a `BooleanQuery` to get the result you want.

```
using Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard;
using Lucene.Net.Documents;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.Search;
using Lucene.Net.Store;
using Lucene.Net.Util;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LuceneSQLLikeSearch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Prepare...
            var dir = new RAMDirectory();
            var writer = new IndexWriter(dir, 
                new IndexWriterConfig(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, 
                new StandardAnalyzer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48)));

            WriteIndex(writer);

            // Search...
            var reader = writer.GetReader(false);

            // Get all terms that end with tulip
            var wildCardQuery = new WildcardQuery(new Term("field", "*tulip"));
            var multiPhraseQuery = new MultiPhraseQuery();

            multiPhraseQuery.Add(new Term("field", "inn"));

            // Get all terms that start with riyadhh
            multiPhraseQuery.Add(GetPrefixTerms(reader, "field", "riyadhh"));

            var query = new BooleanQuery();
            query.Add(wildCardQuery, Occur.SHOULD);
            query.Add(multiPhraseQuery, Occur.SHOULD);

            var result = ExecuteSearch(writer, query);

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Match: {0} - Score: {1:0.0########}", 
                    item.Value, item.Score);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

### WriteIndex

```
public static void WriteIndex(IndexWriter writer)
{
    Document document;

    document = new Document();
    document.Add(new TextField("field", "Tulip INN Riyadhh", Field.Store.YES));
    writer.AddDocument(document);

    document = new Document();
    document.Add(new TextField("field", "Tulip INN Riyadhh LUXURY", Field.Store.YES));
    writer.AddDocument(document);

    document = new Document();
    document.Add(new TextField("field", "Suites of Tulip INN RIYAHdhh", Field.Store.YES));
    writer.AddDocument(document);

    document = new Document();
    document.Add(new TextField("field", "Suites of Tulip INN RIYAHdhhll", Field.Store.YES));
    writer.AddDocument(document);

    document = new Document();
    document.Add(new TextField("field", "myTulip INN Riyadhh LUXURY", Field.Store.YES));
    writer.AddDocument(document);

    document = new Document();
    document.Add(new TextField("field", "some bogus data that should not match", Field.Store.YES));
    writer.AddDocument(document);

    writer.Commit();
}
```

### GetPrefixTerms

Here we scan the index to find all of the terms that start with the passed-in prefix. The terms are then added to the `MultiPhraseQuery`.

```
public static Term[] GetPrefixTerms(IndexReader reader, string field, string prefix)
{
    var result = new List<Term>();
    TermsEnum te = MultiFields.GetFields(reader).GetTerms(field).GetIterator(null);
    te.SeekCeil(new BytesRef(prefix));
    do
    {
        string s = te.Term.Utf8ToString();
        if (s.StartsWith(prefix, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            result.Add(new Term(field, s));
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (te.Next() != null);

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

### ExecuteSearch

```
public static IList<SearchResult> ExecuteSearch(IndexWriter writer, Query query)
{
    var result = new List<SearchResult>();
    var searcherManager = new SearcherManager(writer, true, null);
    // Execute the search with a fresh indexSearcher
    searcherManager.MaybeRefreshBlocking();

    var searcher = searcherManager.Acquire();
    try
    {
        var topDocs = searcher.Search(query, 10);
        foreach (var scoreDoc in topDocs.ScoreDocs)
        {
            var doc = searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.Doc);
            result.Add(new SearchResult
            {
                Value = doc.GetField("field")?.GetStringValue(),
                // Results are automatically sorted by relevance
                Score = scoreDoc.Score,
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        searcherManager.Release(searcher);
        searcher = null; // Don't use searcher after this point!
    }

    return result;
}
```

### SearchResult

```
public class SearchResult
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public float Score { get; set; }
}
```

If this seems cumbersome, note that `QueryParser` can mimic a "SQL LIKE" query. As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485578/181087), there is an option to `AllowLeadingWildCard` on `QueryParser` to build up the correct query sequence easily. It is unclear why you have a constraint that you can't use it, as it is definitely the simplest way to get the job done.