# Issue with using wildcards with lucene .net QueryParser

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net

I have following code for Lucene .Net search:

[image]

If I use query like:

```
AccountId:1 AND CompanyId:1 AND CreatedOn:[636288660000000000 TO 636315443990000000] AND AuditProperties.FriendlyName.NewValue:CustomerId|235
```

It works fine with exact match with CustomerId = 235.

However, if I try to search for a wildcard match like for example:

```
AccountId:1 AND CompanyId:1 AND CreatedOn:[636288660000000000 TO 636315443990000000] AND AuditProperties.FriendlyName.NewValue:CustomerId|*235*
```

it doesn't fetch me any results. I think it is still going for an exact match with value "*235*" Am I missing anything here?

Thanks!

Comment: This query should work fine. Can you debug and show us the value of parser.Parse(query)? Can you replicate in Luke? Also, the single pipe (|) is a bit iffy, as Luke (at least v4.0) considers single pipe a logical OR.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [QueryParser syntax documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/queryparsersyntax.html), the character `|` is not supported. However, it is not very clear whether you intended it to be a logical OR or a literal character.

### Logical OR

The correct syntax for logical OR is either `CustomerId OR *235*`, `CustomerId *235*` or `CustomerId||*235*`.

Also, if this is meant to be a logical OR, you have to allow for a leading wildcard character as pointed out in [Howto perform a 'contains' search rather than 'starts with' using Lucene.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485578/181087).

```
parser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;
```

### Literal `|`

To search for a literal pipe character, you should escape the character so the parser doesn't confuse it with a logical OR.

```
CustomerId\|*235*
```

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not using a leading wildcard in the query as you can see..

Comment: Yes you are - `*235*`. The `*` before the `2` is a leading wildcard.

Comment: The value here is CustomerId|*235*. Note, "CustomerId|" is part of value.