# Storing words with apostrophe in Lucene index

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I've a company field in Lucene Index.
One of the company names indexed is : Moody's

When user types in any of the following keywords,I want this company to come up in search results.
1.Moo
2.Mood
3.Moodys
4.Moody's

How should I store this index in Lucene and what type of Lucene Query should I use to get this behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer depends on the way you want the rest of your index to be built:

 1. Should pluralization be represented? i.e. are "Apple" and "Apples" distinct?
 2. Do you want to keep apostrophes, or can they be obliterated?
 3. Does a company name appear isolated, or inside a larger field?

Comment: thanks for ur comments...my response
1.No
2.I want Lucene not to keep apostrophes
3.Company name may appear isolted as well as in a larger field

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on your clarifications, I want to divide your question into two, and answer each in turn:

1. How do I index words with apostrophes as equivalent to similar words without an apostrophe? e.g. mapping *Moodys* and *Moody's* to the same index term.
2. How do I implement auto-complete search in Lucene - i.e. given an index, find documents using word prefixes, e.g. map *Moo* to *Moodys* ?

1 is relatively easy - Use a [StandardToeknizer](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardTokenizer.html) to create a token combining the apostrophe and s with the previous word, then a [StandardFilter](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardFilter.html) to remove the apostrophe and s. This will convert Moody's to Moody. A [StandardAnalyzer](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer.html) does this and much more (lowercasing and stop word removal), which may be more than you need. Using a stemmer should take both *Moodys* and *Moody* to the same token. Try [SnowBallFilter](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.0/Snowball.Net/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Snowball.SnowballFilter.html) for this.

2 is harder: Lucene's [PrefixQuery](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.Search.PrefixQuery.html), to which Alan alluded, will only work when the company name is the first word in a field. You need something like the answer to [this question about auto-complete in Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120180/how-to-do-query-auto-completion-suggestions-in-lucene).

Answer (score 1):

The StandardAnalyser should work for 3 and 4, however won't work for 1 and 2.

Without writing your own (complex) text analyser, I would think about how you're expecting company names to be searched for.  For example, basic lucene search syntax means that you could find "Moody's" if you search using wildcards: "Moo*" and "Mood*".  Therefore, you might want to consider appending an "*" to the search term before submitting to lucene, however this might cause some confusion if the user isn't aware of this wildcard addition under the hood.