# Generating autosuggestion values like google using lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to create autosuggestion for some of my blogs i already use lucene as search engine and can any one tell me how can i achieve this . Which analyzer will be usefull to generate this, can any one give some code examples too..

Edit.

i am trying to generate the suggestion terms not to display with UI.

Comment: I think you're looking for javascript not java.

Comment: @awm: No, I think Ramesh is looking for the server side part of the solution. Please revert the tag change.

Comment: One possible solution can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120180/how-to-do-query-auto-completion-suggestions-in-lucene. Another one is to just iterate on the term collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at jquery and jquery-ui.  ajax, load, autocomplete is the commands you're looking for.  If you look on jquery.com you'll find a ton of examples as well as doing a search on google for code samples.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality has been ported from Solr to Lucene just recently. Take a look at the [FSTLookup](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_3_0/api/contrib-spellchecker/org/apache/lucene/search/suggest/fst/FSTLookup.html) class, introduced in Lucene 3.3.0. For an example on how to use it, see the associated [test class](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/branch_3x//lucene/contrib/spellchecker/src/test/org/apache/lucene/search/suggest/fst/FSTLookupTest.java).

A small snippet extracted from the test class to show you the basics:

```
private TermFreq[] evalKeys() {
    final TermFreq[] keys = new TermFreq[] {
        tf("one", 0.5f),
        tf("oneness", 1),
        tf("onerous", 1),
        tf("onesimus", 1),
        tf("two", 1),
        tf("twofold", 1),
        tf("twonk", 1),
        tf("thrive", 1),
        tf("through", 1),
        tf("threat", 1),
        tf("three", 1),
        tf("foundation", 1),
        tf("fourblah", 1),
        tf("fourteen", 1),
        tf("four", 0.5f),
        tf("fourier", 0.5f),
        tf("fourty", 0.5f),
        tf("xo", 1),
      };
    return keys;
}

FSTLookup lookup = new FSTLookup();
lookup.build(new TermFreqArrayIterator(evalKeys()));
LookupResult result = lookup.lookup("one", false, 2);
```