# Autosuggestion using lucene

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do query auto-completion/suggestions in Lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120180/how-to-do-query-auto-completion-suggestions-in-lucene)

I am new to lucene and i have an issue with autosuggestion. Currently i am implement the autosuggestion just like the one for google, where you can type "This is" and suggestion include stuff like "This is a good one" etc. But my implementation does not behave the same. It does suggest for a single term only.

Anybody with an idea or solution on how to implement google like autosuggestion will be highly appreciated.