# Need a jQuery Tags Input script with autocomplete and option to add non-existing values

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, tags

I need a jQuery Tags Input script which supports autocomplete but also has an option to allow for non-existing values. It should also support tag-limiting to a certain amount of tags.

I do only use jQuery, not jQuery UI.

I already tried jquery-tagit and jquery-tokeninput.

Does anyone know a solution? Thx!

Comment: Search the web ... be prepared to go down a few more blind alleys.

Comment: If u are .Net user the you may use Lucene AutoComplete Jquery. Check Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120180/how-to-do-query-auto-completion-suggestions-in-lucene

Answer (score 1):

you can use [combo box](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/a-jquery-ui-combobox-under-the-hood) in jQuery.It is very good one.You can use your own values which are not existed in the list.