# Lucene suggest phrases

Tags: java, search, autocomplete, lucene

I have an index with text masses like:

> "Hello I want to try autocomplete  xxx yyy zzz"

Is it possible to get suggestions such that, if I type:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| I typed                    | Suggestion                          |
====================================================================
| autocomplete x             | autocomplete xxx                    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| auto                       | autocomplete                        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Hello I want to try auto   | Hello I want to try  autocomplete.  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So it suggests words based on what is actually after the first word, and won't suggest the words that are before the words I suggest either.

Using lucene 4.4

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968697/how-to-implements-auto-suggest-using-lucenes-new-analyzinginfixsuggester-api/25301811#25301811 for a complete example of doing autocompletion with Lucene.

Comment: However that worked exactly how i didn't want it to work :(

Comment: Ah, sorry. See http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/09/lucenes-new-analyzing-suggester.html for a discussion of AnalyzingSuggester, which I believe will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links might help you:

- [How to do query auto-completion/suggestions in Lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120180/how-to-do-query-auto-completion-suggestions-in-lucene) (one word)
- http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2013/06/a-new-lucene-suggester-based-on-infix.html (multiple words)
- Sample: http://jirasearch.mikemccandless.com/search.py?index=jira