# Index document using StandardTokenizer, LowerCaseFilter and EdgeNgramFilter using Lucence 5.2.0(latest)

Tags: indexing, filter, lucene, tokenize

How can I index documents by applying `StandardTokenizer`, `LowerCaseFilter` and `EdgeNgramFilter` using `lucene 5.2.0` ?

Comment: 5.2.0 isn't the latest version of Lucene.  6.0.0 is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
          <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
        </analyzer>
     </fieldType>
```

with java

```
public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName,
                    Reader reader) {
                TokenStream result = new StandardTokenizer(reader);

                result = new StandardFilter(result);
                result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
                result = new EdgeNGramTokenFilter(result, Side.FRONT,1,20);
                return result;
            }
```

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120180/how-to-do-query-auto-completion-suggestions-in-lucene)

Comment: Thanks but I need in lucene not in solr. I need example in java code using lucene

Comment: okay. below mentioned link might be helpful.  Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() { 
    @Override protected TokenStreamComponents 
    createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        Tokenizer source = 
            new StandardTokenizer(VERSION,reader);
        TokenStream filter = 
            new LowerCaseFilter(VERSION,source);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
    }
};  [https://lingpipe-blog.com/2014/03/08/lucene-4-essentials-for-text-search-and-indexing/]